# multiple items price calculation in C

Tags: c

Hi i am trying to calculate total price for 6 different items and 3 of them must be selected. by using C i tried use switch statement but unfortunately i stuck after 2 selection.
Thank you

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char ch;
    int total=0;

    printf("Which cou will you choose:\n");
    printf("a) cpu 1 \n");
    printf("b) cpu 2 \n");

    scanf("%c", &ch);

    switch (ch)
    {
        case 'a':
            printf("The price is 110 \n");
            total+=110;
            break;

        case 'b':
            printf("The price is 140\n");
            total+=140;
            break;

        default:
            printf("Invalid choice.Switching to next question\n");
    }

    printf("Which ram will you choose:\n");
    printf("q) ram 1 \n");
    printf("w) ram 2 \n");

    scanf("%c", &ch);

    switch (ch) 
    {
        case 'q':
            printf("The price is 10 \n");
            break;

        case 'w':
            printf("The price is 14\n");
            printf("Please Wait\n");
            break;

        default:
            printf("Invalid choice\n");
            break; 
    }

    printf("Which hdd will you choose:\n");
    printf("x) hdd 1 \n");
    printf("y) hdd 2 \n");

    scanf("%c", &ch);

    switch (ch) 
    {
        case 'x':
            printf("The price is 65 \n");
            break;

        case 'y':
            printf("The price is 75\n");
            printf("Please Wait\n");
            break;

        default:
            printf("Invalid choice\n");
            break; 
    }     

  printf("That'll cost %d",total);
  return 0;
}
```

after i add everything once i start program it works only for first switch statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a variable `total` to add up the total cost. Your code will look like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()

{
    char ch;

    int total=0;
    printf("Which option will you choose:\n");
    printf("a) cpu 1 \n");
    printf("b) cpu 2 \n");
    scanf("%c", &ch);

    switch (cpu)
    {
        case 'a':
                printf("The price is 110 \n");
                 total+=110;
                break;
        case 'b':

                printf("The price is 140\n");
                total+=140;
                break;

        default:
                printf("Invalid choice.Switching to next question\n");
                        }
    //ask next question.
    //get input
    //use a switch like the above one
    //add total
    //repeat this as many times you want

    printf("That'll cost %d",total);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for codes but after i add everything once i start program it works only for first switch statement

Comment: @AhmetEminKaradag , Fix the problem by adding a space before `%c` in the `scanf`.